# How to limit the amount of characters entered

Tags: c, string

So, I'm working on a simple password program. I've got this code so far

```
/* simple  password prog */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
        char usrIn[9];
        char password[]={"AXcd8002"};
        do {

        fprintf(stdout,"\n Password:");
        fgets(usrIn,9, stdin);
        if  ( strcmp(usrIn,password)<0 || strcmp(usrIn,password )>0 ) { 
        fprintf(stdout,"\n Password incorrect"); };

        }while( (strcmp(password,usrIn))!=0 );

fprintf(stdout, "\n The password is correct \n");
return 0;
}
```

This code works correctly, if the password is incorrect, the loop will keep going, if it's correct - loop will break. But what doesn't work is this: If the user enters a password with at least one character longer, the program will still say it is correct. 
For instance, if user enters AXcd8002AAA, fgets will read only AXcd8002 , and ignore AAA. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Make buffer bigger than password, isn't that simple? And also strcmp is not safe for passwords because it spends different time for wrong and write passwords, so if you measure time you can determine write and wrong sequences of characters.

Comment: Thank you, Ivan. This is merely class assignment, we're going over strings right now, so that's why it's so simplistic. So I made char usrIn[10] and fgets(usrIn,10,stdin) , it complains the password is incorrect even if i enter correct string

Comment: fgets reads all characters including '\n' (when you click Enter). So first check length before first occurrence of '\n'. If length is good substitute \n with 0 and compare strings (buffer[9] = '\0').

Answer (score 3):

`usrIn` has only 9 characters, of course the extra characters are ignored. Just give `usrIn` enough space:

```
char usrIn[100];
```

And as a best practice:

```
fgets(usrIn, sizeof(usrIn), stdin);
```

---

There's another problem that you didn't consider: the new line character `'\n'` is considered a valid character by `fgets`, so it's also in `usrIn`, you need to remove it manually before comparing passwords.

Comment: I've made suggested adjustments , substituted char usrIn[100]; and fgets(usrIn, sizeof(usrIn), stdin); but now it complains the password is incorrect even if I enter the proper one

Comment: I've added \n to the password, like char password[]={"AXcd8002\n"}; This solves the issue, but probably isn't the best practice, right? You mentioned i need to remove it from fgets, how can that be achieved?

Comment: @Xieerqi Find which character is the `'\n'`, and replace it with `'\0'`.

Comment: Ah, i think i have an idea. For loop is probably appropriate here. Thank you !

Comment: @Xieerqi To eliminate a potential trailing `'\n'`: `size_t len = strlen(usrIn); if (len > 0 && usrIn[len-1] == '\n') usrIn[--len] == '\0';`

Answer (score 0):

Without giving the size of the usrIn giving it dynamic size & performing dynamic input will insert the full password into the array usrIn.

Comment: So I've left char usrIn[]; like this, but now gcc complier gives me this:"password2.c: In function ‘main’:
password2.c:5:7: error: array size missing in ‘usrIn’
  char usrIn[];
       ^
"